# Typescript generate enum from an interface keys with index number

Tags: typescript

I would like to convert this interface to a enum with the index of the element

```js
interface CsvUser {
  firstname: string;
  lastname: string;
  email: string;
  remoteAddress: string;
  team: string;
  role: string;
  post: string;
  site: string;
  workspace: string;
  zone: string;
}
```

to

```js
enum CsvUserColumnId {
  firstname = 0,
  lastname = 1,
  email = 2,
  remoteAddress = 3,
  team = 4,
  role = 5,
  post = 6,
  site = 7,
  workspace = 8,
  zone = 9,
}
```

I only find a way to go from enum to interface but not interface to enum like this

```
type CsvUser = {
  [K in keyof typeof CsvUserColumnId]: string;
}
```

Comment: is the order important? I can think of possible solutions but the TypeScript compiler might change the order without any warning in the future

Comment: yes the order is important it must be the order of the interface

Comment: actually now that I think about it, I think it is not possible to convert an `interface` to an `enum` at compile since `enum`s are a runtime thing and without external tools this might be impossible. The other way around might work though. Is `enum` to `interface` something that would fit your needs?

Comment: I don't see how that would work. Types only exist at compile time, but you need the values of the enum at runtime.

Comment: Not really possible. The order is problematic to begin with (as you mention it's important)  `keyof CsvUser` is a union, union order should not be relied upon as it is an implementation detail. Also you can't go from types (the interface) to values (the enum at runtime). You can go from the enum to the interface if it helps

Comment: Going from the enum to the string is trivial: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwgzgNwKpwgJygXigJQgYwHs0ATAHgGsIRCAzKUSO2RFdGQgGwFcBbAOwCSJADRQ4wNAEt+AcwB8AWABQKiPz4tkqNBx4DhUAN4qoUWlLQT+AQ17RsABhGmonG9bsOoARhfKzCF4bKU4sKAAmfzM0IMJgCABBEhJYuDhwgGZohgg7cIAWHLQubwBWHLBCCXCANhy4KQTwgHYcgHdiCjgwG3xvAA4cgC9Cfm8ATn8AXyA